# react не выводит массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs

вот код:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.catalog.products);
    if (this.state.catalog.products) {
        return (
            this.state.catalog.products.map((item) =>
                <div>
                    {item.description}
                </div>
            )
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>Загрузка...</div>
        );
    }
}
```

его вывод выводит ошибку такого рода: 
`A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Массив, который я пытаюсь вывести:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React не умеет выводить массивы без контейнера (во всяком случае пока). `return` должен возвращать один(!) DOM Элемент или `null`. Вы же возвращаете несколько DOM элементов. Вам необходимо обернуть вывод в какой-нибудь контейнер, например `div` или `span`. Или даже сократить код таким образом:

```js
render() {
    return this.state.catalog.products
        ? (
            <div>{this.state.catalog.products.map((item) =>
                <div>
                    {item.description}
                </div>
            )}</div>
        )
        : <div>Загрузка...</div>;
}
```

Еще вариант

```js
render() {
    return <div>{
        this.state.catalog.products
            ? this.state.catalog.products.map((item) =>
                <div>
                    {item.description}
                </div>
            )
            : 'Загрузка...'
        }</div>;
}
```

Comment: оба ответа помогли

Answer (score 2):

Оберните вот это вот

```
this.state.catalog.products.map((item) =>
            <div>
                {item.description}
            </div>
```

в теги <див> и <закр.див>